# How to implement instant Live update in android?

Tags: android, web-services

I want live update of data in android. I have seen Socket.io which can work in that way in react. I want to know how to use it in android exactly? And is it efficient way to do live update in android native app?

Comment: Please be more specific. Where is this data? If a database, what kind? "Live update" is very vague.

Comment: Would you explain more about how your live update means, do you mean a synchronous streaming of data or other?

Comment: If you carefully see in facebook app, when you like any post users related to  that post get instant update. So I have same functionality in my app. I am using GCM for that currently. But I want to use socket.io instead of that, is there any tutorial which explains client side as well as server side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps talking about something like Google Firebase?  It's a realtime database... and it works on Android... but it also works on much more than Android.

Comment: No I am looking for Socket.io which I can configure on my Server. Is firebase supports iOS as well?

Comment: yes firebase does support IOS also.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt75ZIGdJ4Y